# FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type) UWP/NETCore equivalent

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, codenameone, ikvm, .net-core

Is there an alternative way to create an "uninitialized" object in UWP (NETCore)?  I'm trying to port a piece of code that uses

`object o = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type)`

And then uses ConstructorInfo.Invoke(o, params) to construct the object at a later time.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in UWP (right now, maybe later, who knows?)